# using parameters with max len and check for null vall

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a count for a column to see the max characters.  I'm getting a warning, I know it doesn't effect, but it's more of an annoyance and would like to eliminate the warning.
My example is as follows:

```
Declare @Countthis varchar (255)

select @Counthis = max(len(col1)) from #temp

Print '------- This is the largest count for this column-----' + @Countthis
```

The warning I receive is:

```
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

I tried using `Case` statement but I couldn't figure it out.  If the value is `NULL` just ignore the value.

Is this possible?

Comment: What are your expected results if all values in that column are null?

Comment: Then the Count would be 0 if all values are NULL.

Comment: `max(coalesce(len(col1),0)` perhaps?  0 would show when NULL is only val in col1. warning <> error.  This would run but print would return NULL if all records are null coalesce if you want 0 to show instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
Declare @Countthis varchar (255)

select @Counthis = max(len(IsNull(col1,''))) from #temp
```

Comment: Works perfect, I didn't even think about that!  Thanks!